# How to get friends movies list from facebook php api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to FB php api. I want to get friends movies list. I tried below code

```
$params = array(
'scope' => 'friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'http://mytempurl.php'
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

//attempt1
$movies = $facebook->api("/me/friends/movies");
print_r($movies);

//attempt2
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($friends["data"] as $value) {
        echo '<li>';
        $friend_movie_list = $facebook->api($value["id"] .'/movies');
        print_r($friend_movie_list);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```

Above code gave me array of no values. Please let me know how to get movies list of friends.

Comment: Have you tried your query in the Graph Explorer?

Comment: What permissions has your user granted to your app?

Comment: You need to request the "friends_likes" permission to be able to do this. Did you?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about graph explorer tool. Didn't know about!! Got the movie list using graph explorer